# How to assign a static date to a variable in Scala

Tags: scala, date, static

We are assign a string to a variable integer or long etc.. to a variable like

```
var str:String="This is String"
var inte:Int=1
```

like these

```
var dat:Date=new Date(22/05/2013)
```

this is possible?..

but output is

```
Thu Jan 01 05:30:00 IST 1970
```

How to assign a static date to a variable?..

Comment: You might want to remove the 'static' tag - It isn't relevant to the question, and Scala doesn't have static variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
scala> 22/05/2013
res0: Int = 0
```

You are calling `Date` constructor with an `Int` argument. It's a number of milliseconds since the standard base time known as "the epoch", namely January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT. So you are getting standard base time.

You should use `DateFormat.parse` since all other `Date` constructors are deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

From the question, I couldn't guess what you are trying to achieve..

Perhaps, this is what you are looking for..

```
  import java.util.Date
  import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

  val format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy") 
  var date = format.parse("22/05/2013")          
  // date  : java.util.Date = Wed May 22 00:00:00 IST 2013
```